# scala collection conversions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the most effective way of conversion between different scala.collection object?

E.g.

```
 val a=scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer(1,2,0,3)
```

And I want to get `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`.

1. According to http://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/collections.mutable.png it should be possible by converting to `Buffer` and to `ArrayBuffer` afterwards. Correct?
2. In general, can i make any conversion in scala collection through its common ancestor? (in the previous example the common ancestor is `Buffer`)

PS I read http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html but couldn't find anything about general conversions between various types (i'm aware about .toArray like methods)

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax-wise most effective should be the [`to`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) method introduced in 2.10:

```
def to[Col[_]]: Col[A]
```

> Converts this collection into another by copying all elements.
>   Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.

Use it as `a.to[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer]`.

Efficiency-wise, unless you do an upcast-like conversion where you turn a subtype into a more general collection, converting will involve copying the elements. In your example, it does not matter if you turn the list buffer into a buffer and then into an array buffer -- you can do this directly using `to`, as you cause copying the elements from a linked list into an array either way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. There is just one small problem: a.to[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]] should be changed to a.to[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer] since ArrayBuffer takes no type parameters ..

Comment: You're right - while the array buffer does take type parameters, the `to` method take a higher-kinded type `Col[_]`, and instantiates it for the type of the elements `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering question number 2:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_07).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import collection.mutable._
import collection.mutable._

scala> List(1,2,3,4,5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> res0.to[ArrayBuffer]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> res0.to[ListBuffer]
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

You can convert them as you'd like as long as you keep compatibility:

```
scala> res0.to[Map]
<console>:12: error: scala.collection.mutable.Map takes two type parameters, expected: one
              res0.to[Map]
                      ^
```